# Update Status Facebook C# SDK Question

Tags: c#, vb.net, facebook, sdk

I am trying to write some simple functional code that will be added to an existing large scale project. I used the TweetSharp sdk to get and Access Token & SecretToken, and the stored them, and I can them use those with my API key and secret to post to twitter with no issue. I now need to do the same thing but with a facebook status update. (Someone correct me if I'm wrong), but Facebook doesn't user an Access Token & secret Token, but instead they just use an Access Token. I've written the authorization part of the app that launch the browser, user logs in, click Allow, and then I obtain the Access Token from listening to the URL. I have looked at the documentation for three different SDK/API's and don't see anything specifically related to.. This is how you post a status using the user's Access Token. I have tried a number of API documented methods from the Facebook C# SDK, but they all seem way to complicated compared to how I got this done with Twitter... maybe Facebook just made this more complicated, or maybe the SDK just doesn't offer the functionality..

Can someone point me to an example for Facebook API code that functions like this after getting the AccessToken(The following is a twitter example)

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub TweetButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TweetButton.Click

    'create new Twitter API object
    Dim twitter As New TwitterVB2.TwitterAPI

    twitter.AuthenticateWith("ConsumerKey As String", "ConsumerKeySecret As String", "Token As String", "TokenSecret As String")

    'post to twitter
    twitter.Update(PostTextBox.Text)

    'verify post went through
    MsgBox("Tweet Posted Successfully")

End Sub
```

End Class

#

or maybe the workflow for using Tokens in completely different with FB... any suggestions or help in finding an example of how to get this done would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking for mostly simple functionality in working with Facebook should simply use the built api's to the facebook framework... ie the rest.api or graph.api ... in it's most basic form, you are just shooting http requests at the facebook server with Access Tokens, UID's and other syntax embedded in the url.. I actually find using this easier than the SDK's.

No response needed anymore on this one... Thank you!